# Smoke at post when jumping also is sparking at post when hooking up a short

Tags: battery, jump-start

Trying to jump truck.  Battery post started smoking. Is that because cables were rusty and if you see spark on post when hooking up is that for sure a short?

Answer (score 2):

You will almost always see a spark when hooking up cables - even clean cables.

Bad connections (like through rust) will heat up and if there's material to burn (like the rust) then smoke will be emitted.